# Jersey consuming both application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I want to have something like

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Path("/")
void create(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @ApiParam(required = true) @NotNull @Valid final CreateServiceRequest service);
```

so I can consume both JSON and URL encoded. But when I make a POST request with `-d foo=bar` I get 415 unsupported formatted error.

Is it possible to consume both using the same endpoint? If it is not possible, how do I do automatic validation for the body for URL encoded? I see people use `MultivaluedMap` but that's just a map. I want to make sure the right fields are provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not possible with Jersey (at least I couldn't find an example or documentation for that).
But remember you can extract the common logic into a method, and have two methods for the same with different `@Consumes` directive.

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/")
void createJson(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                        @ApiParam(required = true) @NotNull @Valid final CreateServiceRequest service) {
    create(service)
}


@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Path("/")
void createJson(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                        @ApiParam(required = true) @NotNull @Valid final CreateServiceRequest service) {
    create(service)
}
```

Comment: You need to use `@BeanParam` for the application/x-ww-form-urlencoded method.